# How would i find the posterior distribution in this r function?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to figure out how to find a posterior distribution from an uninformative prior distribution.

My code is -

```
like<-function(x) {dbinom(4. ,10, x)}
integrate(like,0,1)
pi<-seq(0,1, by=0.001)
like<-dbinom(4,10,pi)
post<-function(x) {dbinom(4,10,x)/0.2}
integrate(post,.6,.8)
plot(pi,post,type = "l", col = "red", ylab = "Posterior f(pi)")
```

I keep getting an error message -

Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for this:

```
#Index
like<-function(x) {dbinom(4. ,10, x)}
integrate(like,0,1)
pi<-seq(0,1, by=0.001)
like<-dbinom(4,10,pi)
post<-function(x) {dbinom(4,10,x)/0.2}
integrate(post,.6,.8)
plot(post(pi),type = "l", col = "red", ylab = "Posterior f(pi)")
```

Comment: Finally got it. Thank you. Can you explain the difference to me? How is "pi, post" different from "post(pi)"

Comment: @tako Hi dear. The difference is that the functions use to look for same size vectors. As you added the two vectors, function intended as x and y and that produced the error. Instead you can directly plug the vector in the function and the issue will be alleviated. Hope that was clear enough for you!